# How can I initialize web driver globally?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am working on automation using selenium webdriver , java. Getting **nullpointerexception** and it says driver is null.

My code structure is given below :

**Package Utility**

- Base Class
- Login Class
- App_constant Class

**Package Add user**

- Add user Class

**Utility package code :**

```
 package Utility;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Base {

public static WebDriver driver = null;


//CALL WEB BROWSER AND OPEN WEBSITE
public static void openURL()
{

    try{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(Constant_value_utility.URL);
    }catch(Exception E)

    {
        E.printStackTrace();


    }
}

 }
```

---

```
package Utility;

public class Constant_value_utility {


//OPEN URL
public static final String URL = "Site URL";


//LOGIN FIELDS
public static final String loginbox = "UserName";
public static final String passbox = "Password";

//LOGIN DATA
public static final String username = "test";
public static final String password = "test";
public static final String loginbt = "btnsubmit";

  }
```

---

```
 package Utility;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


 public class Login_Page {

public static WebDriver driver;


public static void login()
{

       Base.openURL();


       driver.manage().window().maximize();

       driver.findElement(By.id(Constant_value_utility.loginbox)).sendKeys(Constant_value_utility.username);
       driver.findElement(By.id(Constant_value_utility.passbox)).sendKeys(Constant_value_utility.password);
       driver.findElement(By.id(Constant_value_utility.loginbt)).click();

  }
```

}

---

**Add user Package code**

```
package Adduser;
import Utility.Base;
 import Utility.Login_Page;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 public class Add_User {

  public static void main(String[] args){
   {


    //LOGIN TO SITE
     Base.openURL();
     Login_Page.login();
    }}}
```

Now My question is I have already created **public static method** openurl() in base class and webdriver is initialized there. But When I call same method in other class of same package and other packages , Why it is giving me nullpointerexception for webdriver?

Is that necessary to write code to initialize webdriver and call browser in every class. How can I initialize web driver globally so I declare it once and can call any where in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your webDriver is declared in the other class too, so

```
   Base.openURL();


   driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

driver is not initialized here.

try to rewrite your `Base.openUrl()` method in order to return the webDriver

edit: your class fields are visible to other classes, thats true. but in order to get the one from the correct class you should try something like `Base.driver`
because `Base.driver != Login_Page.driver`

edit2: here is one example of how a working class could look like

```
   package Utility;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


   public class Login_Page {

   //public static WebDriver driver;


   public static void login()
   {

   Base.openURL();

   //note the change from driver  to Base.driver
   Base.driver.manage().window().maximize();
   Base.driver.findElement(By.id(Constant_value_utility.loginbox)).sendKeys(Constant_value_utility.username);
   Base.driver.findElement(By.id(Constant_value_utility.passbox)).sendKeys(Constant_value_utility.password);
   Base.driver.findElement(By.id(Constant_value_utility.loginbt)).click();
```

}

Comment: Yes I have declared there also because it is not able to call my globally declared web driver from BASE class.. I want like once I call base method it should automatic call web driver also..

Comment: if you use `driver` inside the `Login_page ` class, its implicitly `Login_page.driver`, if you use driver inside the `Base` class, its implicitly `Base.driver`, and as mentioned in my edit, they are not the same

Comment: I see , then can you show me way to call webdriver anywhere from my base class. I do not want to declare web driver any where in project other than base method..

Comment: just remove all declarations of `Webdriver driver;` in all classes except of `Base` and replace everywhere except of in `Base` `driver` with `Base.driver`

Comment: Ohh.. Means driver need to call same like `classname.(dot)methodname`.. Thanks.. But is this standard / right way to call driver...Or I am doing it in wrong way if we see according to some programming standard way...

Comment: according to that, i would use a method to get the driver and make the actual field `private`. in the mentioned method i would return the driver and before i would make sure, that it is not `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80125/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-manuel-jain).